# Springboot LdapTemplate how to query deleted users on interval

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

I need to find the delta of users from AD to synchronize with another AD. Finding the newly created and modified users, with whenCreated and whenChanged attributes I can find those. But when if any users deleted means how to find them? I am using Springboot LdapTemplate to query the AD. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Currently I am using the query to fetch the users.

'''query().where("objectclass").is("person").and("whenCreated").gte(date).and("cn").like("*");
query = query.or("whenChanged").gte(date).and("cn").like("*");

ldapTemplate.search(query,new AttributesMapper() {

@Override
public UserModel mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
usermodel.setCn(null!=attributes.get("cn").get()?attributes.get("cn").get().toString():null);
}'''

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Active Directory, you can match against the `userAccountControl` attribute to query users with disabled accounts. [LdapWiki example](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllAdministrativelyDisabledUsersIeACCOUNTDISABLE2):

```
 (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

The same is mentioned in [these AD examples](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Examples) with a note that provides some context.

> ```
> (&(objectCategory=person) 
> (objectClass=user)
> (userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
> ```
>
> The string 1.2.840.113556.1.4.803 specifies LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND. This specifies a bitwise AND of a flag attribute (an integer), like userAccountControl, groupType, or systemFlags, and a bit mask (like 2, 32, or 65536). The clause is True if the bitwise AND of the attribute value and the bit mask is non-zero, indicating the bit is set.

The value `2` is significant in this context because it is a magic bit defined in [Active Directory Technical Specification 2.2.16 - userAccountControl Bits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/dd302fd1-0aa7-406b-ad91-2a6b35738557):

> **D (ADS_UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE, 0x00000002)**: Specifies that the account is not enabled for authentication.